# Power BI sort by column (Date) is producing different results

Tags: sorting, date, microsoft-powerbi

I have two graphs that are based off of the same dataset. I had an issue with sorting the graph chronologically, so I sorted by a YearMonNum column. The data looks something like this:

| id | YearMonNum | MonthYearShort | Views | Users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 202105 | May '21 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 202106 | Jun '21 | 58 | 42 |
| 3 | 202107 | Jul'21 | 264 | 161 |

And my graphs look something like this in Power BI:
[Image of two graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMNV1.png)

And the problem is that the sort by option on both graphs are different, which I don't understand. If I [click the elipses on the first graph,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeiuS.png) I can sort ascending or descending, whereas the second one doesn't allow sorting ascending or descending. Also, for the first graph, I have to sort by YearMonNum in order for it to [look like the second graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCd3z.png). How do I get both graphs to look like the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Its best to set Sort By definitions once, inside the model (PBIX file) using Power BI Desktop.  Select your **MonthYearShort** column and choose the sort by column of **YearMonNum**. It's a button near the end of the **Column tools** ribbon.

That will work consistently, independent of the settings of any particular visual.